# printCat1(Cat* cat) Vs. printCat2(Cat cat) & More Pointers' Questions

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, struct

The following questions might have been asked already. In addition, I am aware of the fact that there are a lot of posts that discuss the topic. However, after searching, I couldn't find answers to those specific questions.

Note: the questions appear below the code.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 3

typedef struct
{
    const char* name;
    const char* color;
    int age;
}Cat;

void printCat1(Cat* cat)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", cat->name);
    printf("%s\n", cat->color);
    printf("%d\n", cat->age);
    printf("\n");
}

void printCat2(Cat cat)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", cat.name);
    printf("%s\n", cat.color);
    printf("%d\n", cat.age);
    printf("\n");
}

void printCatArray(Cat catArr[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        //WHICH OPTION IS BETTER? (printCat1 OR printCat2)
        //CALLING TO PRINTING FUNCTION.
    }

}

void swap(_____ cat1, _____ cat2)
{
    Cat temp = //cat1 or *cat1 ?
    //cat1 = cat2 or *cat1 = *cat2?
    cat2 = temp;
}

void sortbyage(Cat catarr[])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
            if (catarr[i].age > catarr[j].age)
                swap(______, ______]);
}
int main() {
    Cat catArray[ARRAY_SIZE] =
    { {"cat1", "white", 1},
      {"cat2", "black", 2},
      {"cat3", "gray", 3} };


    printCatArray(catArray);


    return 0;
}
```

*The questions:*

**1**. What is the difference between both functions that print the data of a single cat structure?

**2**. Which printing function is better to use and why? it will be essential and meaningful if you would like to explain.

**3**. What is better to write and why? void swap(Cat cat1, Cat cat2) OR void swap(Cat* cat1, Cat* cat2)

**4**. Is the calling to swap function from the function soryByAge, swap(&catArr[i], &catArr[j]), correct? Would you write it differently?

**5**. The following line of code is correct: catArray[2] = catArray[1];
It will be great to get an explanation about what it actually does.

If one or more of the questions are not clear enough, I will be glad to clarify them.

Thank you very much beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

`printCat1` uses a pointer, it's more efficient because it doesn't make a temporary duplicate.

`printCat2` passes the value, it makes a duplicate of `cat`, it's less efficient.

`swap` function has to use pointers. If it doesn't, it will simply swap  copied values. The original array will be unchanged.

```
void swap(Cat *cat1, Cat* cat2)
{
    Cat temp = *cat1;
    *cat1 = *cat2;
    *cat2 = temp;
}
```

When passing parameter to `swap`, use the address of the variable. For example,

```
swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
printCat1(&arr[i]);
```

The structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    const char* name;
    const char* color;
    int age;
}Cat;

...
Cat catArray[ARRAY_SIZE] =
{ {"cat1", "white", 1},
  {"cat2", "black", 2},
  {"cat3", "gray", 3} };
```

You want to declare strings as character arrays.

```
typedef struct
{ char name[50]; char color[50]; int age; }Cat;
```

Or declare as pointers and allocated dynamically.

Comment: Passing small structs by value may actually be faster, especially combined with inlining. This simplifies aliasing analysis a lot thus gives more opportunities for optimization

Comment: @tstanisl do you mean compiler optimization? In that case the compiler should figure out optimization either way for `const` parameter

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks for replying! As I know, if I pass the array to a function, then I will be able to change its values and the changes will be saved on the function the array was sent from. If so, why in this case pointer to the array is required?

Comment: You are not passing array to the swap function. You are passing an individual element of the array. For this array where elements have fixed length, you can write a different swap function which swaps the array index. Try this with `int arr[3] = {1,5,3};` it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thank you for the explanation. Would you like to explain the following line: `catArray[2] = catArray[1];` ?

Comment: The values from `catArray[1]` are copied to `catArray[2]`. If my answer, or the other answer, is sufficient then click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani is the address of the third node in the array is copied to the address of the second node in the array ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not declare cat name and colour as `const`. If they are defined as `const` you will not be able to change it runtime, for example to get it from the user or read the file with your database.
2. `foo(cat cats[])` and `foo(cat *cats)` are exactly the same as arrays are passed as pointers. It is good to pass the size too as in real life you do not know big the array is.
3. `void swap(Cat cat1, Cat cat2)` OR `void swap(Cat* cat1, Cat* cat2)` - the fist one will work on local copies of the structures. It will not affect the original array. So only the second version will do something meangfull.
4. It is the correct way of doing it. You can also swap structs from the different arrays. You can also add index to the pointer (as in the example below)
5. It copies the whole structure from the index `1` to the structure at index `2`. After that you will have identical elements at indexes `1` and `2`

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    char* color;
    int age;
}Cat;

void printCat1(const Cat* cat)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", cat->name);
    printf("%s\n", cat->color);
    printf("%d\n", cat->age);
    printf("\n");
}

void printCat2(Cat cat)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", cat.name);
    printf("%s\n", cat.color);
    printf("%d\n", cat.age);
    printf("\n");
}

void printCatArray(const Cat *catArr, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printCat1(catArr + i);
        /* or */
        printCat2(catArr[i]);  // in this case the whole structure will passed to the function
    }

}

void swap(Cat *cat1, Cat *cat2)
{
    Cat temp = *cat1;
    *cat1 = *cat2;
    *cat2 = temp;
}

void sortbyage(Cat *catarr, size_t size)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < size; j++)
            if (catarr[i].age > catarr[j].age)
                swap(catarr + i, catarr + j);
}
int main() {
    Cat catArray[] =
    { {"cat1", "white", 1},
      {"cat2", "black", 2},
      {"cat3", "gray", 3} };


    printCatArray(catArray, sizeof(catArray) / sizeof(catArray[0]));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xodsToqxa

Comment: Thanks for replying! On the third point, you wrote it will not affect the original array, but when we pass the array, we actually pass the address of the array.  As I know, if I pass the array to a function, then I will be able to change its values and the changes will be saved on the function the array was sent from. If so, why in this case pointer to the array is required?

In addition, on the fifth point you mentioned,  the address of the seond node (begins from zero) is copied to the third node, so will the third and second nodes point to the same address?